# Clearing text on a Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, text

I've been trying to clear the text on a Javascript canvas for hours, but no matter what I do I can't get to an acceptable solution.
Things I've tried:

- Using clear rect to clear the area around the text; ***problem***: this is not precise enough for what I want.
- Setting the color of the text to the color of the background and writing over the text; ***problem***: the stroke isn't fully cleared. After much suffering I found that you can adjust a canvases line width to make the stroke bigger, but even this isn't working 100%
- Using just stroke text and no fill. ***problem***: Doesn't seem to work, although I may have done it wrong, and honestly it wouldn't look as nice even if it did work.
- Setting the color of the text to the color of the background and writing over the text, but this time copy and pasting the exact same line of code multiple times. ***problem***: This is probably the closest to a real working solution that I've found, but this doesn't really seem right because I am not exaggerating when I say that I am using the exact same line of code multiple times. This seems to imply that each time I run that line of code I get a different result. Overall, I would likely be okay using this as a solution, but I feel like it might end up slowing down my code in the end, so I'd prefer to leave this as a last resort.

I am basing this code off of https://codepen.io/doms/pen/BZLezr and am trying to do it without using p5.js. Anyways, at this point I'm just more annoyed that it's this hard to clear text, as I've googled this issue in about as many different ways that I could think of and have been unable to find a solution. I've attached my code below for reference.

```js
class Particle {
 constructor() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.speed = 1;
  this.width = 30;
  this.font = this.width + "px monospace"
  this.residue = [];
  this.reset();
 }

 reset() {
  this.x = Math.random() * innerWidth;
  this.y = (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
  this.width = (Math.random() * 20) + 10;
  this.font = this.width + "px monospace"

  this.speed = (Math.random() * 0.8) + 0.4;
 }

 update() {
  if (this.y > (innerHeight + this.width)) {
   this.reset();
  }

  this.y += this.speed * 12;
 }

 draw() {

  ctx.font = this.font;
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++){
   if (this.residue.length > 0){
    let tempY = this.residue.pop();
    let tempChar = this.residue.pop();

    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeText(tempChar, this.x, tempY);
    ctx.fillText(tempChar, this.x, tempY);

   }
  }
  
  ctx.font = this.font;
  ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++){
   let char = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor((Math.random() * 109) + 33));
   this.residue.push(char);
   this.residue.push(this.y);

   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.fillText(char, this.x, this.y - (this.width * 0));
  }
 }
}

var run = true;
var particles = [];
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

setInterval(this.draw, 100);


function draw() {

 document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
     if(e.key == 'f'){
      run = !run;
     }
    }

 if (!run){
  return;
 }

 if (particles.length < 120) {
  particles.push(new Particle());
 }

 for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
  particles[i].draw();
  particles[i].update()
 }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Matrix Rain</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't really get your point - but why not simply clear the whole canvas once before calling each particle's draw method?

Comment: @obscure I think I'm just so sleep deprived at this point that I passed over that as a viable solution because I kept thinking about how that would clear all the particles and I guess I thought I just didn't want that.I added the one line to do that after seeing your comment and it works perfectly. I still maintain the position that there should be a way to clear text, but this seems like the easiest solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hehe, you're welcome. I know how it feels to be tired out. ;)